# How do I Filter Multiple Columns with IN clause using AND

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to filter data in several columns based on multiple possible values. 
If I use the statement below I get the matching results but too many. For example if I only pass the Status[Lead, Customer] then I just get those record. If I add SalesRep[cary] then I also get all the matching Cary records which include some with other status like Prospect.

```
SELECT id, `ContactID`, Status, SalesRep, LeadSource, `PhysicalAddress_State`, `PhisicalAddress_Zip`  FROM Contacts WHERE
Status IN ('Lead','customer') OR
SalesRep IN('cary') OR
LeadSource IN ('') OR
PhysicalAddress_State IN ('') OR
PhisicalAddress_Zip IN ('');
```

What I'm looking for is AND So I only get records matching both Status[Lead, Customer] AND SalesRep[cary]

```
SELECT id, `ContactID`, Status, SalesRep, LeadSource, `PhysicalAddress_State`, `PhisicalAddress_Zip`  FROM Contacts WHERE
Status IN ('Lead','customer') AND
SalesRep IN('cary') AND
LeadSource IN ('') AND
PhysicalAddress_State IN ('') AND
PhisicalAddress_Zip IN ('');
```

However if I change the ORs to ANDs I don't get any records unless there is a selection for each field. How can I get AND to work if I don't have a value to search on?

Comment: It might be that LeadSource is equal to null and not ''

Comment: maybe try only adding things to the where if you are going to search for it. Like if you are only looking for records that have a status of 'lead' or 'customer', leave out the rest of the where.

Comment: Also, this isn't a real problem, but you should have tables that store the status, sales reps, and lead sources and your contacts table should store the IDs from those rather than the full names. You will save a ton of space doing that

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I think @Echtniet has it right - "IN" is funny with blanks and nulls. Why not just check if LeadSource != '' and so on?

Comment: Strawberry's link is something you should keep in mind for any future questions, but is pointless for this one. The other guys are also wrong. Your problem is that you are searching for things you don't want to search for. Don't put something in the `where` unless you are searching for it

Comment: @CptMisery it looks to me like they are trying to retrieve data only if LeadSource is empty. So something like LeadSourse IS NULL. At least that is what i understand based on their sql statement.

Comment: You have to be able to change which columns are in the `where`. Your first query is saying get all records where the status is 'lead' or 'customer' and all records where the salesrep is 'cary' and all records where leadsource is an empty string. The second query is saying get all records where the status is 'lead' or 'customer' and the salesrep is 'cary' and the leadsource is an empty string. From your description, it sounds like you want to use the second query, but you shouldn't include leadsource in the where when you don't care what it is.

Comment: Yes not having them in the WHERE would be the right solution however I can only pass parameters for the IN, example IN :leadsource which is rendered as IN('Tim'). I can't add to the WHERE statement. This means all the IN statements must be there to use them if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a way to not include the fields in the WHERE this is what I came up with:

```
SELECT id, `ContactID`, Status, SalesRep, LeadSource, `PhysicalAddress_State`, `PhisicalAddress_Zip`  FROM Contacts WHERE
IF(true, Status IN ('Closed'), id != 0) AND
IF(true, SalesRep IN('Cary'), id != 0) AND
IF(false, LeadSource IN (''), id != 0) AND
IF(false, PhysicalAddress_State IN (''), id != 0) AND
IF(true, PhisicalAddress_Zip IN ('87123'), id != 0);
```

For my environment:

```
SELECT id, `ContactID`, Status, SalesRep, LeadSource, `PhysicalAddress_State`, `PhisicalAddress_Zip`  FROM Contacts WHERE
IF(:includeStatus, Status IN :status, id != 0) AND
IF(:includeSalesRep, SalesRep IN :SalesRep, id != 0) AND
IF(:includeLeadSource, LeadSource IN :LeadSource, id != 0) AND
IF(:includePhysicalAddress_State, PhysicalAddress_State IN :PhysicalAddress_State, id != 0) AND
IF(:includePhisicalAddress_Zip, PhisicalAddress_Zip IN :PhisicalAddress_Zip, id != 0);
```

Thank you for your advise!